# Visual Studio 2013 shows HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I created a project in VS 2010 with SQL Server 2008 R2 and it runs correctly. When I try the same project in VS 2013 and SQL Server 2014, it shows the home page but when I click the next tab it shows an error.. I want to publish this website to Azure please give me a instruction how to figure it out these two problem

> HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
>
> Most likely causes:
>   The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.
>   Things you can try:
>   Check the failed request tracing logs for additional information about this error. For more information, click here.

Comment: Can you share the URL which you get AFTER you click the tab. I am assuming your site is public.

Comment: http://localhost:61495/   this page is shown  but http://localhost:61495/Account/DLogin     is show error   please explain clearly

Comment: This is not a public URL , this is your local URL :-/